# Image is cropped when exiting the svg

Tags: d3.js, svg, c3.js

I'm putting pictures on top of the bars. But the image of the bar with the highest value is cut. How can I do to enlarge the graph or what can I do so that the image is not cropped.

(I am not very skilled with svg and d3.js)
https://jsfiddle.net/htyu6uLo/

```
   var aColoresChart=["#5DD255","#D4D4D4","#EA4335"];
    var chart = c3.generate({
      bindto: '#chart',
      data: {
          columns: [
                [1,5,6,7]
          ],
          color: function(color, d) {
             return aColoresChart[d.index];
          },
          type: 'bar',
          labels: true, //to display the labels in the bar chart
          bar: {
                width: {
                    ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
                }
          }
      },
      size: {
                height: 235
            },
            bar: {
                width: 35
            },
            padding: {
                left: 40
            },
          tooltip: {
            show: false
          },
          legend: {
            show: false
          },
          axis: {
          x: {
              type: 'category',
              categories: ['one','two', 'three']
          },
          y:{
            tick: {
              format: d3.format('f'),
              count:7
            }
          }
      },
  });


  d3.selectAll('#chart .c3-texts text.c3-text')
    .each(function(d,i){

      var barposition= d3.select(this);
      d3.select('#chart .c3-texts').append('image')
        .attr("xlink:href", 'https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/happy-emoticon_318-40206.jpg')
        .attr("x", function(){ return barposition.attr('x')-20; } )
        .attr("y", function(){ return barposition.attr('y')-47; })
        .attr('text-anchor','middle')
        .attr('class','topimage')
        .attr("width", 50)
        .attr("height", 50);
  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `max` in the axis

In your case the data:
              `columns: [
                    [1,5,6,7] //here 7 is max
              ],`

So if you give max of 10 in the

```
   y:{
        max: 10,//give it a higher max number than the data max we have.
        tick: {
          format: d3.format('f'),
          count:7
        }
      }
```

working sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rb1c9nvn/)

Comment: can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230566/make-a-chart-of-x-vs-y-in-c3-js